# How to automatically generate variations on a font from a single .ttf file?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

In search of Hebrew fonts, I've come across a site specializing in just such fonts. When you select any of the fonts from the catalog, you are directed to a page, where you are offered a sandbox in which to test the font. In the following sequence of screenshots, you can see the results of my testing a font named `Choco` by applying to it the bold, italic, bold+italic, and underline settings.

[image: Upright]

[image: Bold]

[image: Italic]

[image: Bold and italic]

[image: Underlined]

When I downloaded the `Choco` font, only a single file was downloaded: `Choco.ttf`. How was the sandbox able to vary the font without having dedicated files for the sundry variations? Is it possible to accomplish the same with LaTeX, and in particular with the `fontspec` package?

Comment: see the FakeBold and FakeSlant keys

Comment: As for underlining, only very few fonts come with a special style, so underlining is almost always done via some computation. Have a look at the `soul` package for this, for example. It is possible to fake boldness and slant a font via `fontspec`: Search for `FakeBold` and `FakeSlant` in the manual.

Comment: @JasperHabicht with lualatex underlining should be done with the lua-ul package, that is more stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice given in the comments to my original post, here's a LaTeX document demonstrating `fontspec`'s `AutoFakeBold` and `AutoFakeSlant` options, as well as `Lua-UL`'s `\underLine` command. In order for this example to compile successfully, a TrueType font file needs to be available at the path `./Fonts/Choco.ttf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Choco}[
   Path = Fonts/ ,
   Extension = .ttf ,
   AutoFakeBold = 1.5 ,
   AutoFakeSlant = 0.25
]
\usepackage{lua-ul}
\begin{document}
בדוק את זה כאן...\par
\textbf{בדוק את זה כאן...}\par
\textit{בדוק את זה כאן...}\par
\textit{\textbf{בדוק את זה כאן...}}\par
\underline{בדוק את זה כאן...}\par
\underLine{בדוק את זה כאן...}
\end{document}
```

When compiled with `lualatex`, with the TrueType file being the one downloaded from the site described in my original post, a PDF file resulted, which, when opened in a PDF viewer, displayed as follows. (Only the relevant part of the page was included in the screenshot.)

[image: Fake bold, and fake slant]

When compared with the screenshots embedded in my original post, it can be seen that the `AutoFake...` options had a similar effect to the one seen in my original post. However, the LaTeX underlining is not similar, and is less sophisticated than the one seen in my original post. I wonder how the underlining seen in my original post was produced.